# how to set the width of page element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

there is a tool bar in the left of my page, the width of the tool bar is 35px, the main content panel is in the right of my page and has CSS `float:right` I want to set the width of main content panel with 100%-35px, so that the tool bar can be displayed, how can I achieve this effect, many thanks.

Comment: hi gays, your solutions also can works, I find my solution.as my main penal has a jquery plugin, so when setting the position with absolute the format will be disordered, `margin-left` is a good idea, my solution is use jquery to init the size, `   var m_width = window.screen.width;$("#reportContent").css({width:m_width-402}); `, it also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). But i'm not sure about browser compatibility. So try jquery solution.

Layout should be like this.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div id="toolbar" style="display: inline-block; width: 35px"></div>
    <div id="main-content" style="display: inline-block"></div>
<div>
```

in jquery:

```
$("#main-content").width($(window).width() - 35);
```

if there is padding or margin detect them also.

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to do this by using `absolute` position. It doesn't need to use javaScript and it handle screen size change event correctly.
the css like bellow:

```
.toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
}

.content { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m4rfe/) in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS based approach:

css:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.toolbar {
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  padding: 0 5px; 
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="toolbar col">
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
    <li>Link3</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="main col">
    <p>This is the place holder for Main Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://cdpn.io/hlfFG

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this can easily be done with CSS.

```
#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
```